# How can I get drop down menu value still selected after form is submitted (2)?

Tags: php, mysql, input, drop-down-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get drop down menu value still selected after form is submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780297/how-can-i-get-drop-down-menu-value-still-selected-after-form-is-submitted)

When I type in data in a text box and submit the form, the data is still stored in the text box which is great For example I used . What I want to do now is that when a value is selected from a drop down menu and the form is submitted, I want the value chosen to still be shown as the selected value on the drop down list but I cannot manage to do this. Any ideas?

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Exam Interface</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="mobile_app";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");



$sessionid = isset ($_POST['sessionid']) ? $_POST['sessionid'] : "";
$moduleid = isset ($_POST['moduleid']) ? $_POST['moduleid'] : "";
$teacherid = isset ($_POST['teacherid']) ? $_POST['teacherid'] : "";
$studentid = isset ($_POST['studentid']) ? $_POST['studentid'] : "";
$grade = isset ($_POST['grade']) ? $_POST['grade'] : "";
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : "";

$sessionid = mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid);
$moduleid = mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid);
$teacherid = mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid);
$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string($studentid);
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($grade);

?>

<p><strong>NOTE: </strong>If a search box is left blank, then the form will search for all data under that specific field</p>

<form action="exam_interface.php" method="post" name="sessionform">        <!-- This will post the form to its own page"-->
<p>Session ID: <input type="text" name="sessionid" value="<?PHP print $sessionid ; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Session Id here-->
<p>Module Number: <input type="text" name="moduleid" value="<?PHP print $moduleid ; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Module Id here-->
<p>Teacher Username: <input type="text" name="teacherid" value="<?PHP print $teacherid ; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher here-->
<p>Student Username: <input type="text" name="studentid" value="<?PHP print $studentid ; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
<p>Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" value="<?PHP print $grade ; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Grade here-->
<p>Order Results By: <select name="order" value="<?PHP print $orderfield ; ?>">
<option value="ordersessionid">Session ID</option>
<option value="ordermoduleid">Module Number</option>
<option value="orderteacherid">Teacher Username</option>
<option value="orderstudentid">Student Username</option>
<option value="ordergrade">Grade</option>
</select>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php

$username="u0867587";
$password="31may90";
$database="mobile_app";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");



$sessionid = isset ($_POST['sessionid']) ? $_POST['sessionid'] : "";
$moduleid = isset ($_POST['moduleid']) ? $_POST['moduleid'] : "";
$teacherid = isset ($_POST['teacherid']) ? $_POST['teacherid'] : "";
$studentid = isset ($_POST['studentid']) ? $_POST['studentid'] : "";
$grade = isset ($_POST['grade']) ? $_POST['grade'] : "";
$orderfield = isset ($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : "";

$sessionid = mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid);
$moduleid = mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid);
$teacherid = mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid);
$studentid = mysql_real_escape_string($studentid);
$grade = mysql_real_escape_string($grade);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

switch ($orderfield) {
    case 'ordersessionid': $orderfield = 'gr.SessionId';
    break;
    case 'ordermoduleid': $orderfield = 'm.ModuleId'; 
    break;
    case 'orderteacherid': $orderfield = 's.TeacherId';
    break;
    case 'orderstudentid': $orderfield = 'gr.StudentId'; 
    break;
    case 'ordergrade': $orderfield = 'gr.Grade';
    break;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId WHERE ('$sessionid' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '$sessionid') AND ('$moduleid' = '' OR m.ModuleId = '$moduleid') AND ('$teacherid' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '$teacherid') AND ('$studentid' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '$studentid') AND ('$grade' = '' OR gr.Grade = '$grade') ORDER BY $orderfield ASC");

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

echo "<p>Your Search: <strong>Session ID:</strong> "; if (empty($sessionid))echo "'All Sessions'"; else echo "'$sessionid'";echo ", <strong>Module ID:</strong> "; if (empty($moduleid))echo "'All Modules'"; else echo "'$moduleid'";echo ", <strong>Teacher Username:</strong> "; if (empty($teacherid))echo "'All Teachers'"; else echo "'$teacherid'";echo ", <strong>Student Username:</strong> "; if (empty($studentid))echo "'All Students'"; else echo "'$studentid'";echo ", <strong>Grade:</strong> "; if (empty($grade))echo "'All Grades'"; else echo "'$grade'"; echo ", <strong>Order Results By:</strong>";if ($orderfield == 'gr.SessionId') echo " 'Session ID'"; else if ($orderfield == 'm.ModuleId') echo " 'Module Number' "; else if ($orderfield == 's.TeacherId') echo " 'Teacher Username' "; else if ($orderfield == 'gr.StudentId') echo " 'Student Username' "; else if ($orderfield == 'gr.Grade') echo " 'Grade' ";"</p>";

echo "<p>Number of Records Shown in Result of the Search: <strong>$num</strong></p>";

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Student Id</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Session Id</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Mark</th>
<th>Module</th>
<th>Teacher</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

 echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StudentId'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Forename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SessionId'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Grade'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Mark'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ModuleName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TeacherId'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

}

mysql_close();


 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank You

Comment: Please just edit your previous question...

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that worked or helped you out.  Also upvote answers that you think were appropriate answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of your page, with far too many changes to mention. If you don't understand anything, feel free to ask...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>Exam Interface</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php

      $username="xxx";
      $password="xxx";
      $database="mobile_app";

      mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
      @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

      foreach (array('sessionid','moduleid','teacherid','studentid','grade','orderfield') as $varname) {
        $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }

      switch ($orderfield) {
        case 'ordersessionid':
          $orderfield = 'gr.SessionId';
          $ordername = 'Session ID';
          break;
        case 'ordermoduleid':
          $orderfield = 'm.ModuleId'; 
          $ordername = 'Module Number';
          break;
        case 'orderteacherid':
          $orderfield = 's.TeacherId';
          $ordername = 'Teacher Username';
          break;
        case 'orderstudentid':
          $orderfield = 'gr.StudentId'; 
          $ordername = 'Student Username';
          break;
        case 'ordergrade':
        default:
          $orderfield = 'gr.Grade';
          $ordername = 'Grade';
          break;
      }

    ?>
    <p><strong>NOTE: </strong>If a search box is left blank, then the form will search for all data under that specific field</p>

    <form action="exam_interface.php" method="post" name="sessionform">        <!-- This will post the form to its own page"-->
      <p>Session ID: <input type="text" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Session Id here-->
      <p>Module Number: <input type="text" name="moduleid" value="<?php echo $moduleid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Module Id here-->
      <p>Teacher Username: <input type="text" name="teacherid" value="<?php echo $teacherid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher here-->
      <p>Student Username: <input type="text" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter User Id here-->
      <p>Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" value="<?php echo $grade; ?>" /></p>      <!-- Enter Grade here-->
      <p>Order Results By:
        <select name="orderfield">
          <option value="ordersessionid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'ordersessionid') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Session ID</option>
          <option value="ordermoduleid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'ordermoduleid') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Module Number</option>
          <option value="orderteacherid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'orderteacherid') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Teacher Username</option>
          <option value="orderstudentid"<?php if ($orderfield == 'orderstudentid') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Student Username</option>
          <option value="ordergrade"<?php if ($orderfield == 'ordergrade') echo ' selected="selected"' ?>>Grade</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>

    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $query = "
          SELECT * FROM Module m
            INNER JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
            JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
            JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."' = '' OR m.ModuleId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."' = '' OR s.TeacherId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."' = '' OR gr.StudentId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."' = '' OR gr.Grade = '".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."')
          ORDER BY $orderfield ASC";

        $num = mysql_num_rows($result = mysql_query($query));
        mysql_close();

    ?>

    <p>
      Your Search:
      <strong>Session ID:</strong> <?php echo (empty($sessionid)) ? "'All Sessions'" : "'$sessionid'"; ?>,
      <strong>Module ID:</strong> <?php echo (empty($moduleid)) ? "'All Modules'" : "'$moduleid'"; ?>,
      <strong>Teacher Username:</strong> <?php echo (empty($teacherid)) ? "'All Teachers'" : "'$teacherid'"; ?>,
      <strong>Student Username:</strong> <?php echo (empty($studentid)) ? "'All Students'" : "'$studentid'"; ?>,
      <strong>Grade:</strong> <?php echo (empty($grade)) ? "'All Grades'" : "'$grade'"; ?>,
      <strong>Order Results By:</strong> '<?php echo $ordername; ?>'
    </p>
    <p>Number of Records Shown in Result of the Search: <strong><?php echo $num ?></strong></p>
    <table border='1'>
      <tr>
        <th>Student Id</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Session Id</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>Mark</th>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Teacher</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "
      <tr>
        <td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Forename']}</td>
        <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
        <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
        <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
        <td>{$row['TeacherId']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
      ?>
    </table>

    <?php
      }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to say a big thank you for organizing the code for me. It looks a lot more clearer and easier to read. This will be great for me when it comes to reading it and it will be great for my supervisor in university  to look at and being able to read it. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Order Results By: <select name="order" value="<?PHP print $orderfield ; ?>">
<option value="ordersessionid" <?php echo ($_POST['name'] == 'ordersessionid') ? 'selected="true"' : ''; ?>>Session ID</option>
<option value="ordermoduleid"  <?php echo ($_POST['name'] == 'ordermoduleid') ? 'selected="true"' : ''; ?>>Module Number</option>
<option value="orderteacherid"  <?php echo ($_POST['name'] == 'orderteacherid') ? 'selected="true"' : ''; ?>>Teacher Username</option>
<option value="orderstudentid"  <?php echo ($_POST['name'] == 'orderstudentid') ? 'selected="true"' : ''; ?>>Student Username</option>
<option value="ordergrade"  <?php echo ($_POST['name'] == 'ordergrade') ? 'selected="true"' : ''; ?>>Grade</option>
</select>
```